# API REST Verbe-type use GET instead of POST

Tags: vb.net, rest, api

i have a problem that i don't understand. I communicate with API, in my function i write this :

```
        ...
        oRequest = WebRequest.Create(cUrl & "/Arbres/Ajouter")
        oRequest.Method = "POST"
        oRequest.ContentType = "text/json"
        ...
        Using writer As New StreamWriter(oRequest.GetRequestStream)
            writer.Write(cJSON)
            writer.Flush()
        End Using
        ...
        Using Response As WebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse
            Using dataStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
                    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

My Verb-type is POST, but sometimes i receive the next error message :

***Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type, a request verb-type is GET***

"WebRequest.Create" normally intialize a new instance no ?

How is it possible that the verb is "GET" when I enter a type of "POST" verb well ?

Would it be possible that a request of type "GET" is not correctly closed in a thread and that the code would resume this request instead of my request of type "POST" ?

Comment: The first line of your code seems to have nothing to do with the other three. Are you under the impression that it does?

Comment: yes, thanks i have delete this line, do not consider it ^^.

Comment: the MS sample shows how to POST data using WebRequest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Comment: ty codebrane but i use and close my response as your example, this error appears only once every n times and not every times.